# directive with nested directive and repeat not rendering

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 directives, one of them is recursive and the other renders a form with a select option. Everything appears to be working, but the select box is empty in the ui but the angular comment is inside of the inspection. I have tried to compile the result in multiple way but I cannot get the options to appear. The options are in a repeat and I think that is what is causing it. Here are my 2 directives. Thanks for the help.

select options

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("typesControl",function($compile,$timeout){
    return {
        replace: true
        //THESE OPTIONS DO NOT SHOW UP IN THIS SELECT
        ,template: '<select name="name" class="form-control"><option ng-repeat="type in design.types" ng-selected="{{type.id == content.partid}}">{{type.name}}</option></select>' 
        ,compile: function (element, link) {
            var contents = element.contents().remove();
            var compiledContents;
            return {
                pre: function (scope, element) {

                }
                ,post: function (scope, element) {
                    if (!compiledContents) {
                        compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                    }
                    compiledContents(scope, function (clone) {
                        element.append(clone);
                    });
                    element.change(function () {
                        var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
                        var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
                        var $container = $form.find('.formtemplate');
                        var tpl = '';
                        //THESE INPUTS DO RENDER
                        tpl += '<div><input type="text" name="ids" placeholder="ids" class="form-control" value="{{content.ids}}"></div>';
                        tpl += '<div><input type="text" name="classes" placeholder="classes" class="form-control" value="{{content.classes}}"></div>';
                        switch (val) {
                            case 'Partial':
                                tpl += '<select name="content" class="form-control"><option ng-repeat="link in links" ng-selected="{{link.url == content.content}}">{{link.url}}</option></select>';
                                break;
                            case 'View':
                                break;
                            case 'Source':
                                break;
                        }
                         element.removeAttr('types-control');
                         $container.empty().append(tpl);
                         $compile($container)(scope);
                         if (!scope.$$phase) {
                            scope.$apply();
                         }
                    });
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element.trigger('change');
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

recursive directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive("tree", function($compile,$timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {family: '='}
        ,template:
            '<div class="row" ng-repeat="content in family | orderObjectBy:\'orderby\':false" style="margin-top: 25px;">'+
                '<div class="col-lg-6">'+
                    '<form class="simple-form">'+
                        '<div types-control ></div>'+
                        '<div class="formtemplate"></div>'+
                        '<button ng-click="newcontent(content.id)" type="submit" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>'+
                        '<button ng-click="deletecontent(content.id)" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></button>'+
                    '</form>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div tree family="content.children"></div>'+
            '</div>'
        ,compile: function(element, link){
            var contents = element.contents().remove();
            var compiledContents;
            return {
                pre: function(scope, element){

                }
                ,post: function(scope, element){
                    if(!compiledContents){
                        compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                    }
                    compiledContents(scope, function(clone){
                        element.append(clone);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

EDIT: I created this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EeZ13hKbbix9jbEBxxfz?p=preview) which shows the problem with the select boxes.

Comment: could i know the reason why you required `terminal` here?

Comment: I am not getting any errors and I was doing some testing, I just forgot to remove terminal. I have edited my question to remove terminal. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into this problem, it is related to the scope. Using `scope` inside a directive the way that I am passing `family` in creates an isolated scope. This means that you have to pass the other variables in using attributes. Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EeZ13hKbbix9jbEBxxfz?p=preview)

```
scope: {
  family: '='
  ,links: '='
  ,types: '='
}
```